# How to set just one method to private in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, oop

I have a class with N methods. I want to set one of these methods to private. How can I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
 class Example
    def methodA
    end

    def methodP
    end

    private :methodP
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this way:

```
class Example
    def public_method1
    end

    private def used_by_public_method1
    end

    def public_method2
    end
end
```

Another option (that I find more confusing):

```
class Example
    def public_method1
    end

    def public_method2
    end

    private

    def used_by_public_method1
    end

    # Don't accidentally put public methods down here.
end
```